# Is there a term for combination WITH order?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

Suppose we are selecting elements from some set of $n$ elements. First we are taking one of $n$, then we are taking one of $n-1$ and so on. We are stopping after $k$ elements done and considering order in the result.

Is there a name of such operation in English? In Russian it has special name "размещение".

The number of these combinations is

$A_n^k = n^{\underline k} = n(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-k+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

where $n^{\underline k}$ is ["falling factorial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: This is sometimes called "permutations of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time."

Comment: Aren't they "k-permutations" also?

Comment: maybe "variations" ? In German , they are sometimes called "Variationen"

Comment: @Dims Something of the wording should tell there are $n$ things. Depends on both $n$ and $k.$

Comment: You could say "$k$-permutations of an $n$ element set".